# Get list of WP Updates Across Sites

Tags: php, wp-query, updates

Is there a way to query a WP site to see the number of updates currently available?  I'm not really looking for a list of the actual updates, just the number.  This would be the total number of Plugin/Theme/Core updates, like it is listed in the WP admin menu.

I manage multiple WP sites across multiple servers and would like an easier way of knowing when updates are available, rather than checking them individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question but, I wanted to post this here for reference, since I never accepted an answer.

This functionality is now easily achieved using the Jetpack centralized dashboard. You can administer updates to all your connected WP sites.

http://jetpack.me/2014/12/16/jetpack-3-3-a-single-home-for-all-your-wordpress-sites/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the http://managewp.com/ to maage all your sites from one dashboard.

From site

> ManageWP helps you manage all your WordPress sites from one location,
>   keeping them updated and secure.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into `wp-admin/includes/update.php` file. There you can see `get_core_updates()`, `get_plugin_updates()` and `get_theme_updates()` functions. Eeach function returns array of required updates. So you need just summarize counts of these arrays:

```
$total_updates = count( get_core_updates() ) + count( get_plugin_updates() ) + count( get_theme_updates() );
```

Comment: I like this idea but, given the require functions/includes/credentials, I would likely have to include this directly in update.php right?  Which would then be overwritten if the the core is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [wpremote.com](http://wpremote.com) as well. I don't think it has as many features as ManageWP, but it's free.

Comment: Good suggestion but, I'm not really crazy about the idea of entering the WP logins on a 3rd party site.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is a 3rd party service that will aggregate all your sites' update status and several have been mentioned already.

There is another one that's free also, http://worpit.com that gives you full view on your updates across all your sites.

Hope that helps give you some other options.